# HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In my .NET5 WebApi application, I am continuously getting below in the log:

```
[2022-03-07 13:34:34 DBG] Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 0.0348ms - processed: 0 items - remaining: 2 items
[2022-03-07 13:34:44 DBG] Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 2 items
[2022-03-07 13:34:44 DBG] Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 0.0064ms - processed: 0 items - remaining: 2 items
[2022-03-07 13:34:54 DBG] Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 2 items
[2022-03-07 13:34:54 DBG] Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 0.0031ms - processed: 0 items - remaining: 2 items
[2022-03-07 13:35:04 DBG] Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 2 items
[2022-03-07 13:35:04 DBG] Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 0.0044ms - processed: 0 items - remaining: 2 items
[2022-03-07 13:35:14 DBG] Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 2 items
[2022-03-07 13:35:14 DBG] Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 0.0121ms - processed: 0 items - remaining: 2 items
[2022-03-07 13:35:24 DBG] Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 2 items
```

This continues to happen, sometimes endlessly. Seems it's a cleanup cycle and takes up to long minutes to finish. Can anyone help me to understand why this is happening? and how to resolve it?

Comment: Why two minutes? Timestamps show not even a second change and the message itselfs says it takes 0.0076ms(!).

Comment: @Christian.K - I have just added two lines for example. This happens continuously. Editing the post.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you use the HttpMessageHandler inside your application?

Comment: I haven't used or defined HttpMessageHandler from my application. In Startup.cs, I used service.AddHttpClient() and inject HttpClient from controller's constructor

Comment: ya i'm having the same issue. the remaining count keeps climbing too. i register httpClient in startup.cs as a named client. I inject httpClientFactory into a typed client. the http requests use the factory to create the named client using CreateClient("name"). then the result client is used via using client.GetAsync() and the typed client is injected into the controller and a background service. the background service is logging these cleanup logs. seems like message handlers not getting released.

Comment: I'm have some problem (

Comment: same problem here, anyone found a solution?

Comment: @advapi -Please check my answer post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching a bit, I found that it's actually a log generated during Http cleanup cycle from .net. It's actually not a problem, rather some helpful logs.

> The HttpMessageHandler class in .NET uses connection pooling to
> improve performance when making multiple HTTP requests to the same
> endpoint. When a request is made, the HttpMessageHandler creates a new
> HttpClientHandler and HttpClient instance, and adds them to the
> connection pool.
>
> After the request is completed, the HttpMessageHandler instance will
> release the HttpClient and HttpClientHandler instances back to the
> connection pool. This process is known as cleanup.
>
> You may see logs related to the cleanup cycle because some logging
> frameworks will log whenever an object is disposed or finalized, which
> happens during the cleanup process. These logs can be useful for
> debugging or performance analysis, but they can also be noisy and
> clutter up your logs.
>
> If you are seeing an excessive number of cleanup cycle logs, it could
> be a sign of a performance or resource usage issue. For example, if
> you are creating and disposing of HttpMessageHandler instances too
> frequently, you may be putting unnecessary strain on the connection
> pool and causing excessive cleanup cycles. In that case, you may want
> to consider reusing HttpMessageHandler instances or optimizing your
> usage patterns to reduce the number of requests made.